# Is there any difference between a stream's Longitudinal Profile and its Elevation Profile?

Tags: elevation, gis-principle, profile

I have derived elevation profile of a river channel using USGS SRTM 1 ArcSec. I am interested to know whether Elevation Profile and Longitudinal Profile are synonymous?

Comment: Same thing in my opinion

Comment: I have skimmed through Google but didn't find any reference, could you please provide any reference for more clarification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [elevation profile](http://geokov.com/education/elevation-profile.aspx) or a topographic profile is a two-dimensional cross sectional view of the landscape. It provides a side view of the relief of the terrain along a line drawn between two locations on a topographic map.

Whereas, the [longitudinal profile](https://training.fws.gov/courses/CSP/CSP3200/resources/documents/LongPro_AFG2013.pdf) is a two-dimensional view along the river, and it characterizes average stream slopes and depths of riffles, pools, runs, glides, rapids and step/pools. Longitudinal profiles are measured in the downstream direction.

In your case you said you have derived elevation profile of a river channel, which I think it is longitudinal profile.

Comment: So I would have to indicate riffles, runs, glides etc on the Elevation Profile plotted from Digital Elevation Model to call is as 'Longitudinal Profile'?

Comment: I just had a walk 5 km long, started at point a, took a road B and use road c to return to point a. If I want to represent elevation change along the route I think both items will do

Answer (score 0):

Both are same. Longitudinal elevation is Elevation along the line or stream line.

But Cross section elevation is elevations across the line.